# notebook to execute Databricks job

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

Is there an api or other way to programmatically run a Databricks job. Ideally, we would like to call a Databricks job from a notebook. Following just gives currently running job id but that's not very useful:

```
dbutils.notebook.entry_point.getDbutils().notebook().getContext().currentRunId().toString()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To run a databricks job, you can use `Jobs API`. I have a databricks job called `for_repro` which I ran using the 2 ways provided below from databricks notebook.

**Using `requests` library:**

- You can create an access token by navigating to `Settings -> User settings`. Under `Access token` tab, click generate token.
- Use the above generated token along with the following code.

```
import requests
import json

my_json = {"job_id": <your_job-id>}    

auth = {"Authorization": "Bearer <your_access-token>"}

response = requests.post('https://<databricks-instance>/api/2.0/jobs/run-now', json = my_json, headers=auth).json()
print(response)
```

[image]

- The `<databricks-instance>` value from the above code can be extracted from your workspace URL.

[image]

**Using %sh magic command script:**

- You can also use magic command %sh in your python notebook cell to run a databricks job.

```
%sh

curl --netrc --request POST --header "Authorization: Bearer <access_token>" \
https://<databricks-instance>/api/2.0/jobs/run-now \
--data '{"job_id": <your job id>}'
```

[image]

- The following is my job details and run history for reference.
  [image]

Refer to [this Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/2.0/jobs?source=recommendations) to know all other operations that can be achieved using `Jobs API`.